# G Suite Admin SDK Groups API subscriptions for changes occurred or similar delta API?

Tags: directory, google-api, google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

I have this API call https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/members/list to get the list of members in a group. But I need also to sync the modified/deleted data in the same after initial sync. That is, I am unable to find any delta call for a list of groups G Suite Admin SDK Groups API or any Pub-Sub model of this. If these don't exist in which way I  have to proceed to achieve this.

Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure which programming language you are using, but e.g. in Apps Script you can use time-driven timers to refresh your results and in Javascript polling.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Admin Reports API, here is a direct link to the groups_enterprise activities:

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/activities/list?apix_params=%7B%22userKey%22%3A%22all%22%2C%22applicationName%22%3A%22groups_enterprise%22%7D

You can monitor groups in realtime with push notifications.